# Graph of "piecewise" function without kinks in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, piecewise

I'm trying to replicate the graph below:
[image]

My code is the following:

```
fun1 <- function(x){
  314.32*x^2.413
}

fun2 <- function(x){
  350-0.7136*50/x^(2.413*6)
}


fun3 <- function(x){
  2500-4.37136*500/x^(2.413*4)
}

gg1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 3)), 
              aes(x = x))+
  stat_function(fun = fun1)+
  stat_function(fun = fun2)+
  stat_function(fun = fun3)`

gg2 <- gg1 + ylim(0, 2500)

print(gg2)
```

The code works but I want the first function only for values of `x <= 1`, and the other two functions only for values of `x > 1`. I tried to play with xlim but nothing worked so far. In addition, I don't want kinks at `x = 1`, but I'm really confused about how to add a smooth-pasting condition.

Beginner here, so a simple solution is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this solution:

```
fun1 <- function(x){
  ifelse(x<=1, 314.32*x^2.413, NA)
}

fun2 <- function(x){
  ifelse(x>1, 350-0.7136*50/x^(2.413*6), NA)
}


fun3 <- function(x){
  ifelse(x>1, 2500-4.37136*500/x^(2.413*4), NA)
}

library(ggplot2)
gg1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 3)), 
              aes(x = x))+
  stat_function(fun = fun1, n=1001)+
  stat_function(fun = fun2, n=1001)+
  stat_function(fun = fun3, n=5001)

gg2 <- gg1 + ylim(0, 2500) 

print(gg2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Marco! This doesn't get rid of the kink at x=1 (which maybe is just not possible) but it's otherwise what I was looking for.